# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ant

Still trying to make heads or tails of the hopelessly out-of-date [official spring tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html).

This time, it's the error in subject:

```
c:\Users\mkumpan\Projects\Spring testing\build.xml:152: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64
<stack trace dump omitted>
```

This class is actually contained in tomcat-util.jar:

```
bash-3.1$ pwd
/c/Program Files/Tomcat/lib
bash-3.1$ jar -tf ./tomcat-util.jar | grep Base64
org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64.class
```

And I'm pretty darn sure that I included it in build.xml:

```
<fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

I even tried to be more explicit:

```
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\" includes="tomcat-util.jar">
```

Nothing works, I still get that message every time I try to run any tomcat-related targets. Could someone, perhaps, suggest a line of investigation?

Google doesn't seem to provide anything [relevant](https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=cr&ei=5PMuUpSsN4HV4gS92IDIBA#newwindow=1&q=NoClassDefFoundError%20%22org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64%22).

**Update:**
Full master-classpath reference provided below.

```
<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>
```

Comment: Which part of the 'build' is failing? I put build in quotes as `NoClassDefFoundError` is a runtime exception, and so I think your app will be compiling fine. Also, what version of Tomcat? My version has the jars in TOMCATHOME/lib, not TOMCATHOME/bin.

Comment: @Paul Grime, The app is compiling fine. This is part of an ant deployment script which is supposed to run Tomcat tasks. Any tomcat task I try launching fails with this error. The pre-deploy part, the app build itself is successful.

Comment: Could be a classpath issue. Those can get pretty mystifying…

Comment: @DonalFellows, It could be. But that's the funny part, all and any other dependencies work fine, except for this one. Wouldn't be asking if I knew if/where my classpath is screwed up. :\

Comment: which targets fail? Do you set this classpath in the `taskdef` definition? Peraps it is used by the tasks but not in the classloader they are loaded from.

Comment: @akostadinov, You nailed that one, by the looks of it. I didn't notice that the `taskdef`s all have a different classpath ref, and that one skimped out on tomcat-util.jar. Post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Tomcat does odd things inside itself with class loaders; screwups are _entirely_ possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrong pathref was used for the necessary targets, one that did not contain a path to the much-needed `tomcat-util.jar`.

Kudos to @akostadinov for the prod in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the following tomcat related entries in build.xml and build.properties the ant deployment should work in tomcat 7 and above

```
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"
             war="${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
    <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
    <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
    <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}/text"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>

<!-- End Tomcat tasks -->
```

and also make sure following entries are added in tomcat-users.xml in tomcat installation/conf dir

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="kanchan" password="kanchan" roles="manager,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: In Tomcat 8 adding a line <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/> helped

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might stumble upon this issue with tomcat 7. It looks as if **org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64** was added into tomcat-coyote.jar in version 7.0.39.

So I think the options:

- update to 7.0.39+
- use it from somewhere else **org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64** (commons-codec:commons-codec)

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 8 it appears the relevant library is "tomcat-util.jar" rather than tomcat-coyote :-)

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat version `7` and above, just include `tomcat-util.jar` in your `build.xml` file

```
<fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
    ...
    <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    ...
</fileset>
```